# ListBox SelectionChanged event : get the value before it was changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a C# wpf application in which there is a listbox, and I'd like to get the value of the element that was selected before a change occur

I succeeded in getting the new value this way :

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"... />

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test.add(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

But I would need something like `listBox1.UnselectedItem` to get the element that was unselected during the change. Any idea ?

Comment: The value should be in the event args.

Comment: @Taekahn If you know of a simple way to get the value from `EventArgs` then I would recommend posting an answer

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) to the rescue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `SelectionChangedEventArgs` has a property called `RemovedItems` which contains a list of items that were removed with the new selection. You can replace `EventArgs` with `SelectionChangedEventArgs` and access the property of the parameter (Casting would also work, because it is a subclass).

```
    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> oldItemNames = new List<string>();
        foreach(var item in e.RemovedItems)
        {
            oldItemNames.Add(item.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to have a `private int _selectedIndex` that stores the value from the SelectedIndex property, like so:

```
private int _selectedIndex;

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test.add(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

    // grab the _selectedIndex value before we update it.
    var oldValue = _selectedIndex;
    _selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

   // code utilizing old and new values
   // oldValue stores the index from the previous selection
   // _selectedIndex has the value from the current selection
}
```

Comment: Ok, I guess I could have thought of it myself ! thank you for writing the whole thing down too :-)

Comment: Good answer. You actually sparked my interest with something related to this.